# SELECT из двух таблиц c использованием LIMIT

Tags: mysql, запрос, select, база-данных

У нас есть 2 таблицы.

```
users
userID   name
1        Имя 1
2        Имя 2
3        Имя 3

user_contact
contactID     userID       FirstField       secoundField
1               1          val of Имя 1     Это для Имя 1
2               1          val of Имя 1     Это для Имя 1
3               3          val of Имя 3     Это для Имя 3
```

Суть проблемы в том что нужно вытащить больше полей, не только FirstField.
Такой запрос вытаскивает только 1.

```
SELECT u.*,
(
SELECT `FirstField` 
FROM `user_contact` v 
WHERE u.`userID` = v.`userID` 
limit 1
) as `userID`
FROM `users` u;
```

Результат этого запроса

```
userID   name      FirstField
1        Имя 1     val of Имя 1
2        Имя 2     null
3        Имя 3     val of Имя 3
```

Мне нужно
userID   name      FirstField         secoundField
1        Имя 1     val of Имя 1       Это для Имя 1
2        Имя 2     null               null
3        Имя 3     val of Имя 3       Это для Имя 3

ORDER BY не канает т.к использует много ресурсов.

Comment: Стоит ли использовать еще 1 SELECT для выборки второго столбца ?
Или есть другие методы ?

Comment: вы нормально можете описать таблицы  - user_contact contactID userID FirstField secoundField 1 1 val of Имя 1 Это для Имя 1 2 1 val of Имя 1 Это для Имя 1 3 3 val of Имя 3 Это для Имя 3  -вот это вообще что?

Comment: Да я отформатировал нормально, но когда отправил, получилось это :(

Comment: отредактировал val of Имя 1 - вот это что значит?  Это для Имя 1 - это что??

Я как то смутно себе представляю что вы хотите хранить в таблице user_contact.  С табл users - как то все понятно -просто имя юзера и иего уникальный индекс - правильно?

Comment: FirstField = Первая поле
secoundField = Второе поле
val of Имя 1 это просто значение ( просто назвал ее так что бы было понятно что userID совпадает с Имя 1 )

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
SELECT u.*,
(
SELECT `FirstField`,`secoundField`
FROM `user_contact` v 
WHERE u.`userID` = v.`userID` 
limit 1
) as `userID`
FROM `users` u;
```

А вообще использование подзапросов не айс (иногда без них не реально) . Напишите что должен возвращать запрос в виде таблицы

Чисто интуитивно догадка - вот вам запрос:

```
Select users.*, user_contact.FirstField, user_contact.secoundField
FROM users left join user_contact
on users.userID=user_contact.userID
```

Comment: Вот интуитивно + нужно добавить LIMIT только 1 поле. 
а у меня выводит все поля из contacts ( дублируються )

Comment: 2 ой запрос правильный?

Answer (score 0):

прочитал несколько раз - не осилил, что же вам таки надо?
если не получается на словах, то, хотя бы ради примера покажите таблички:
исходные
что надо получить.
Зачем сортировка нужна пока не ясно и почему она в вашем случае так накладна также не понятно.
LIMIT - получение точно N записей. Без сортировки не имеет смысла - ибо БД не гарантирует в какой последовательности будут записи (один и тот же запрос может вернуть по разному).
И покажите в таблицах на более понятных значениях -

```
1----1----вася----пупкин
2----1----вася----непупкин
```

и т.д.